# ELF section to segment mapping and RWX rights

Tags: linux, elf

I have a classic "Hello world" C program built on Linux with gcc. The segments and sections in the built binary look like this:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x00001b 0x00001b R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000884 0x000884 R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x00fdc8 0x000000000001fdc8 0x000000000001fdc8 0x000270 0x000278 RW  0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x00fdd8 0x000000000001fdd8 0x000000000001fdd8 0x0001e0 0x0001e0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000798 0x0000000000000798 0x0000000000000798 0x00003c 0x00003c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x00fdc8 0x000000000001fdc8 0x000000000001fdc8 0x000238 0x000238 R   0x1

Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

1. Does this mean that the sections: *.note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r* are mapped into program memory as executable? Why aren't they read-only?
2. What do RWE rights (flags) mean in terms of "special" segments like NOTE, DYNAMIC, INTERP?